# extract a number in a strings regardless its position

Tags: python

i am trying to extract '2' and '5' in a string whatever what the user_Input is but the digits at most is 5 .If the user_input contain no '2' and '5' i wish to produced a blank space.This is my coding and i am new to programming

```
while '2' or '5' in dice_remains:
    extract2 = dice_string.find('2')
    extract5 = dice_string.find('5')
    value_generated1 = dice_string[extract2]
    value_generated2= dice_string[extract5]
    answer = value_generated1 + value_generated2
    dice_remains = dice_string[extract2:]+dice_string[:extract2]+dice_string[extract5:]+dice_string[:extract5]
```

Comment: The dice_remains ls obtained from a def function so it would be quite tedious to show it here.

Comment: you should give an example of `dice_remains` and `dice_string`

Comment: @PRMoureu dice_string can be made up at most of 5,4,3,2,1 digits.It is generated by a random.randrange and convert to string to sum them up.In this case dice_string is "55126"

Comment: and dice_remains =dice_string.

Comment: The condition will test true if EITHER digit is in the string. But if only one is in the string and not the other, find will return -1, and you will get the last element in dice_string. I'm pretty sure this is not what you want.

Comment: `find` returns only the position of first occurred character/substring, can you be more clear with your input and output values? E.g, input: give concrete examples for `dice_remains` and `dice_string` and expected output for the same

Comment: i trying to make the find() function to keep execute until it get rid of all the '2' and '5' from the string.From there, i am trying to print all the '2' and '5' extracted from the string. i am not sure whether my way of thinking could apply in this way but if u guys could provide alternative method then it would be great.

Comment: @anusha i am trying to make the dice_remains = dice_string because i want the while loop to stop executing by adding a break statement without changing the original string.I am not sure whether a variable inside a while loop would change its original string from above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Irrespective of number of digits in input, extract only required values 2 and 5 into another string.

```
a = 6572
print a
b = str(a)
c=""
for i in b:
    if i=='2':
        c = c + i
    if i == '5':
        c = c + i   
print c
```

Comment: use an `or` condition to combine the two `if blocks`.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are planning to do ?

```
 no_acc =[] ; other_acc =[]
 for pos in range(len(dice_string)):
    if dice_string[pos] == '2' or dice_string[pos] == '5':
       no_acc.append(dice_string[pos])
    else:
       other_acc.append(dice_string[pos])
 print ''.join(no_acc)
 print ''.join(other_acc)
```

Comment: what is pos? :)

Comment: it is the index of dice_string. Run it here http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=edit to see what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

If it is removing from string, we can use string replace:

```
a = 12345
print a
b = str(a)
b = b.replace('2', ' ')
b = b.replace('5', ' ')
print b
```

Output:
12345
1 34

Comment: i need to to extract the '5' and '2' from any possible inputs in  which the digits at most is 5,4,3,2,1.For example,if my dice_string is '56789' the output is 5.Second example,if my dice_string is '6572' the output is 52.This also applies to 3,2,1 digits

Comment: a = 6572
    print a
    b = str(a)
    c=""
    for i in b:
        if i=='2':
            c = c + i
        if i == '5':
            c = c + i 
    print c